# How to dispose of Serilog 2.0 correctly in ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

According to [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/2.x-Upgrade-Guide), when an application is shutting down, it is recommended to dispose of Serilog using either

```
 Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

or in case you have an instance variable to `.CreateLogger()`, call its

```
.Dispose();
```

When building ASP.NET Core app in Visual Studio, it generates `Program` and `Startup` classes, neither of which implements `IDisposable`. Are we supposed to add this interface to `Program` so that we have a way to dispose Serilog directly?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, ASP.NET [calls into dispose](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggerFactory.cs#L51) of the logger providers and so its the responsibility of the individual providers to do any clean up.

But looks like Serilog's logger provider does not do anything in its dispose method:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/master/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/SerilogLoggerProvider.cs

I would suggest to post a question on the Serilog's repo.

Comment: Raised a ticket for discussion here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/issues/41 (thanks Kiran)